# Ambiguous user defined conversions, when converting from X to Y. C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I wanted to know the reason behind allowing to define redundant conversion implementations in different classes but displaying a failure while trying to consume them.

```
        public class Celsius
        {
            public Celsius(float temp)
            {
                Degrees = temp;
            }

            public float Degrees { get; }

            public static explicit operator Fahrenheit(Celsius c)
            {
                return new Fahrenheit((9.0f / 5.0f) * c.Degrees + 32);
            }
            public static explicit operator Celsius(Fahrenheit fahr)
            {
                return new Celsius((5.0f / 9.0f) * (fahr.Degrees - 32));
            }
        }

        public class Fahrenheit
        {
            public Fahrenheit(float temp)
            {
                Degrees = temp;
            }

            public float Degrees { get; }

            public static explicit operator Fahrenheit(Celsius c)
            {
                return new Fahrenheit((9.0f / 5.0f) * c.Degrees + 32);
            }
            public static explicit operator Celsius(Fahrenheit fahr)
            {
                return new Celsius((5.0f / 9.0f) * (fahr.Degrees - 32));
            }
        }
```

The above code will not show any error. But while trying to consume it, it'll show ambiguous code implementation error.

```
        Fahrenheit fahr = new Fahrenheit(100.0f);
        Celsius c = (Celsius)fahr;

        Console.Write($" = {c.Degrees} Celsius");
        Fahrenheit fahr2 = (Fahrenheit)c;
```

Is there a way to specifically choose the specific type-cast implementation?
Is there any reason behind not preventing redundant implementations by the framework?
Please guide me in a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to have 2 cast operators for each type. You should just have the C to F conversion in your `Fahrenheit` class and vice versa.

Comment: yes, but what if I have both of them. Why does framework didn't restrict it to not to have duplicate conversions.

Comment: @sree its not up to the framework. the compiler just doesn't know how they are used and likely doesn't tract that information.

Comment: I understood, it works if I have only cast operation per each type. I'm more interested in this scenario. The definitions os both the classes are seemingly correct. But they cannot be consumed. Is there a way to consume them, specially in this case.